# Html.Action not passing parameter to Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action method signature of which is:

```
public ActionResult ViewContest(int id, int showNext){
//Some code here
}
```

In one of my views, I have this:

```
<a href="@Html.Action("ViewContest", "Home", new { id = Model.UserActivity.UserParticipation.CompetitionId, showNext = 1 })">
    <img src="~/Image/RightArrow.png" style="float:right;width:40px;" />
</a>
```

When I run the program, the view passes the "id" value to the method correctly but the runtime throws an exception for showNext being null. Why is my showNext value not passing to the method? Any ideas?

Comment: What is the rendered html?

Comment: `@Html.Action()` calls a server method. your creating a link so you want `@Url.Action()`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure if I'm clear on the question. The Html.Action is displaying an image of an arrow that when clicked is supposed to call the action method for new data. Does this answer the question or you want the code for the view?

Comment: That is not what your code is doing. You need to us `@Url.Action()` - look at the html your generating and the `href` attribute. Its not clear from your comment what your trying to do. What does your `ViewContest()` controller method return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You re using wrong helper. To generate url to `ViewContest` method of `Home` controller use:

```
@Url.Action("ViewContest", "Home", new { id = Model.UserActivity.UserParticipation.CompetitionId, showNext = 1 })
```

So eventually your code should look like:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("ViewContest", "Home", new { id = Model.UserActivity.UserParticipation.CompetitionId, showNext = 1 })">
    <img src="~/Image/RightArrow.png" style="float:right;width:40px;" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for their input.